# How to run script in already open browser in Selenium Serenity BDD

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

I am using Serenity BDD framework and I want to run script in already open browser , I am not sure how to do this through **Serenity.Properties** file.
[Serenity Properties](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/docs/reference/serenity-properties#serenitydrivercapabilities)